# Ratio of energy of normal modes of string

Tags: waves, string

Suppose there's a wave on a string represented by fourier series:

$$y(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1} \sin(nx)\cos(nct)$$

I know the energy is $\propto y^2 n^2$, where $y$ is the displacement and $n$ is the normal mode level.

Is the energy ratio between the fundamental mode and third mode given by:

$$(\frac{2}{1})^2 (\frac{1}{5})^2 = \frac{4}{25}$$?

Why is the second excited mode less energetic than the ground mode?

Comment: Is $x$ the displacement or $y$?

Comment: Yes, the displacement is y

Comment: So you can edit your post to fix the 2nd sentence.

Answer (score 2):

For a string of linear density $\mu$ and tension $T$ and length $L$, the normal modes are given by
$$y_n(x,t)=A\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{L}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{L}\sqrt{\frac{T}{\mu}}t\right)$$
assuming initial condition $y_n(x,0)=0,$ and $A$ being the amplitude.

Notice that at $t=0$ the string is flat, and so all energy is in the form of kinetic energy. Since $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2,$ the total energy of $y_n$ is given by
$$E_n=\int_0^L\frac{1}{2}\mu\left(y_n^{(0,1)}(x,0)\right)^2\,dx=\frac{A^2n^2\pi ^2 T}{4 L}.$$
Hence, the energy ratio between $y_1$ and $y_3$ is $\frac{E_1}{E_3}=\frac{1}{9},$ and not $\frac{4}{25}$ (I'm not sure how you got that number).

Interestingly, $E_n$ is independent of $\mu$.

#### Mathematica Code:

```
f[x_, t_] := A Sin[\[Pi] n x/L] Sin[(n \[Pi] Sqrt[T])/(L Sqrt[\[Mu]]) t];
Refine[Integrate[1/2 \[Mu] D[f[x, t], t]^2 /. t -> 0, {x, 0, L}], 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]
```

Comment: Displacement for different modes are different. They have a factor of $\frac{1}{2n+1}$.

Comment: @user44840: Okay. In that case, letting $f(n)=\frac{n^2}{(2n+1)^2}$, you obtain $f(1)/f(3)=49/81$, not $4/25$.

Comment: the third mode is n = 2. So it's 25/4 actually. So the ground state has more energy than the third.

Comment: @user44840: No, the third mode is $n=3$. The first mode is $n=1$, since $n=0$ isn't actually a mode (it's zero, and thus has zero energy).

Comment: @user44840: Also, could you explain how you get 25/4? I tried computing $f(n)/f(m)$ for various values of $m,n$ but was unable to obtain 25/4 (or 4/25) for any choice of $m,n$. In any case, the reason why one mode has more energy than another mode is by definition: you wrote down a state that describes the evolution of the initial state $y(x,0)=\frac{1}{2}-\text{SawtoothWave}\left(\frac{x}{2\pi}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ under the wave equation. The fact that one mode has more energy than another is a consequence of the initial conditions that you are given; there is nothing fundamental about it.